# Sony Vaio Ubuntu installation won't boot afterwards

Tags: boot, grub2, vaio

It may seem like a duplicate question, but it's not. I have a Sony Vaio that I installed Ubuntu 15.10

It was not a dual boot. During installation, I picked "erase everything and install ubuntu". Still after installation, it tries to boot into Windows, and Vaio care recovery options show up. Of course recovery is not an option because I cleaned up the drive. Still, somehow vaio recovery remains. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's UEFI. As far as I understand, some manufacturers write code into UEFI to make the computer to try booting Windows every time. Sony Vaio apparently is one of those models.

I found the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196415). It's using efibootmgr to delete "Windows Boot Manager" entry and add a Ubuntu boot entry.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196415

Answer (score 0):

Is the laptop UEFI? If so the BIOS will need to know what to boot. This page has some info on the settings required that may be helpful.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI